# Am i following the right way in comparing the two arraylists

Tags: java

I will have the two Arraylists values from my Database, I will have the two ArrayLists with the same number of elements and with the same order.

I was doing a test for which I was required to compare two ArrayLists.

The following is a sample program to demonstrate the approach I followed.
Please let me know if there a loop holes, which can arise which I might miss.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("Ravi");
        list1.add("fdfsd");
        list1.add("Sai");


        list2.add("Ravi");
        list2.add("fdfsd");
        list2.add("Sai");

        if(list1!=null && list2!=null){
                if(list1.size()==list2.size()){
                    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
                        if (!list1.contains(list2.get(i))) {
                            System.out.println("Mismatch");

                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                        if (!list2.contains(list1.get(i))) {
                            System.out.println("Mismatch");

                        }
                    }
                }else if(list1.size()!=list2.size()){
                    System.out.println("Mismatch");     
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: You are checking this two times. no need second for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need that 2nd loop. The 1st loop will itself do the job. And secondly, what's wrong with using `list1.equals(list2);`? From [`List#equals(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) doc:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the `equals` method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

So, `equals()` will work, only if the order of elements in your lists are same. Also, this won't work in the case, where the element types of the `Lists` do not override `equals()` method, for e.g.:

```
List<int[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(new int[] {1, 2});
List<int[]> list2 = Arrays.asList(new int[] {1, 2});

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2));  // false
```

So, for `List<E>.equals()` method to work, the element type `E` must override `equals()` and consequently, `hashCode()` too. In your case, since you are having `String` as element type, it would work fine (unless of course, the order of elements is different).

For e.g., this would also fail:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("b", "a");
list1.equals(list2);  // false
```

So, if order matters, in the sense, if you are not sure whether the list elements are in the same order, then you can *sort* both the lists, and then perform `equals()`:

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);
list1.equals(list2);  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was doing a test for which i was required to compare two ArrayLists .

There are many Util methods in `List` interface to check this.

I guess you need `containsAll()`  method .

> Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)

In case they are not coming in order ,

Do sort before comparing

```
  Collections.sort(list1);
  Collections.sort(list2);
```

Then compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`List#removeAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method and check the size of the list after the second list is removed from the first. If its greater than 0, then its a mismatch. You need to first check the size though!

Something like this:-

```
if (list1.size() == list2.size()) {
    list1.removeAll(list2);
    if (list1.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Match!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Mismatch!");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Mismatch!");
}
```